# Why sysdate-'dd-mm-yyy' is not valid in-spite of internal conversion being possible?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

`'dd-mm-yy'` being `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` it is implicitly converted to `Date` data type during comparison, insertion but why is not converted during a arithmetic operation.

```
sysdate>'01-01-17' //is valid
sysdate-'01-01-17' //is in valid
```

First I assumed the operators(+,-,..) are only for numeric data type. Later I got to know these operators are used even in [*Date Arithmetic*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196492) and even operands with `Date`data type are also valid.

*"During arithmetic operations on and comparisons between character and noncharacter datatypes, Oracle converts from any character datatype to a numeric, date, or rowid, as appropriate"* -
[doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51030)

Using `to_date` solves the issue. I am looking for the reason why it is not implicitly converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget implicit conversion.  Just express your dates using explicit date literals:

```
sysdate > date '2017-01-01'
sysdate - date '2017-01-01'
```

The code is clearer and less ambiguous as well.

As to why Oracle doesn't do implicit conversion in the second case.  Oracle doesn't know what type to expect.  The second operand could be either a date or a number, so it doesn't know how to convert the string.  In the first case, the comparison should be to a date.

Comment: I was assuming the similar reason which does not allow the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more detail on Gordon Lindoff's answer with an example.

During `sysdate>'010117'` as your comparing with a date '010117' surely should be date and is implicitly converted. Same going during insert.

But during `sysdate-'010117'` the system has the possibilities of converting it Number or Date, and it chooses to convert into Number. So `'dd-mm-yy'` format is tried to convert into Number in this context.